How to capture a set of lightning fast windows on linux mint cinnamon?
I've noticed a set of windows recently which appear for but a single frame on my linux mint cinnamon install before closing. I'm not sure which program opens these windows, or what the intentions of these windows are.
Is there a way to see the logs of cinnamon, or the X server, specifically which programs open / close windows? and if so,is there a way to find the culprit of these windows?

Cinnamon uses a logging system called syslog, an you can view the logs using the journalctl command:
sudo journalctl -u cinnamon --since=yesterday | grep 'window manager'

The X server also logs events too.:
sudo journalctl -u systemd-logind -u Xorg --since=yesterday | grep 'window'

Obviously, depending on a few things, your window manager might be called something other than window manager for cinnamon or window for Xorg.
